# Can I change the position of a disk partition?

Tags: gparted, partitioning

Every time I boot ubuntu, I get this message :

[image: disk space remaining]

To solve that problem I need to increase the ubuntu partition size, but here is the situation:

[image: gparted]

ubuntu is installed on *ext4*

So the question is: Can I decrease *Windows8-OS's* size, then delete *linux-swap*, then make *ext4* use the unallocated space generated in the previous step and then create the *linux-swap* partition after *ext4* ? Wouldn't it mess up Ubuntu booting as a consequence of changing the *ext4's* first address?

By the way, I don't know why I have so many partitions nor if they're all necessary. If possible, I would appreciate some explanation about it.

Comment: You have the right idea. I'd first backup your important data. Resize the Windows NTFS partition from within Windows (not gparted) and then reboot Windows a couple of times. When I need to move/resize a EXT4 partition, I tend to move the entire partition left, then resize to the right. You'll have to boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD to make any changes.

Comment: @heynnema " I tend to move the entire partition left, then resize to the right" -> won't it mess up ubuntu booting as a consequence of changing the ext4's first address?

Comment: No... giggle... it's not like Windows :-) Just remember that if you change partition UUID's, like if you recreate swap, make sure you `sudo blkid` and edit `/etc/fstab` with the new UUID.

Comment: While you're at it, I'd probably make swap bigger. How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @heynnema I have 8GB of RAM.

Comment: I'd change your swap from 2G to 8G then. Have you started to make changes yet?

Comment: @heynnema no, I haven't done any changes yet. I'm waiting to borrow a external disk so I can backup before making any changes.

Comment: Before you make any Windows partition changes, in Windows, open an administrative command prompt window, and type `chkdsk /f c:` and approve to run it at next reboot. Now reboot. This will make sure that your Windows file system doesn't have any errors before you start moving things around.

Comment: ps: all the "extra" partitions are for booting, and original manufacturers diagnostic and software restore partitions. Don't touch them.